# How can I use JavaScript's functionality to create a calculator without using eval?

Tags: javascript, html

It's a little mess, but I need JavaScript's function to calculate. I avoided using `eval` because my teacher has not taught that. Can help me with it?

```js
function A7() {

  var num = document.getElementById(7).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A8() {

  var num = document.getElementById(8).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A9() {

  var num = document.getElementById(9).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A10() {

  var num = document.getElementById(10).value;

  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num


}

function A4() {

  var num = document.getElementById(4).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A5() {

  var num = document.getElementById(5).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A6() {

  var num = document.getElementById(6).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A11() {

  var num = document.getElementById(11).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A1() {

  var num = document.getElementById(1).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A2() {

  var num = document.getElementById(2).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A3() {

  var num = document.getElementById(3).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A12() {

  var num = document.getElementById(12).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

function A0() {

  var num = document.getElementById(0).value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
}

var firstNum = getElementById(display);
document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num

var secondNum = getElementById(display);
document.getElementById("display").value = document.getElementById("display").value + num
operation = "";

function calculate() {
  if (operation = "+") {
    firstNum + secondNum;
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum + secondNum;
  } else if (operation = "-") {
    firstNum - secondNum;
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum - secondNum;
  } else if (operation = "/") {
    firstNum / secondNum;
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum / secondNum;
    else {
      firstNum * secondNum;
      document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum * secondNum;
    }
  }
```

```html
<BODY>
  <form>
    <TABLE>
      <TR>
        <TD COLSPAN="4">
          <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="display" style="text-align:right">
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="7" ID="7" onclick="A7()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="8" ID="8" onclick="A8()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="9" ID="9" onclick="A9()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="/" ID="10" onclick="A10()">
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="4" ID="4" onclick="A4()"> </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="5" ID="5" onclick="A5()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="6" ID="6" onclick="A6()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="*" ID="11" onclick="A11()">
        </TD>
      </TR>
      <TD>
        <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="1" ID="1" onclick="A1()">
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="2" ID="2" onclick="A2()">
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="3" ID="3" onclick="A3()">
      </TD>
      <TD>
        <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="-" ID="12" onclick="A12()">
      </TD>
      <TR>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="0" ID="0" onclick="A0()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="C" ID="C">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="=" ID="14" onclick="calculate()">
        </TD>
        <TD>
          <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="+" ID="13" onclick="A13()">
        </TD>
      </TR>
</BODY>
```

Comment: im not sure if its a copy paste error but you missed a } after the last else if

Comment: And you're missing a closing `</form>` tag

Comment: `var firstNum = getElementById(display);` You've never set the variable `display`. I suspect you meant to quote it.

Comment: You use the same thing to set `secondNum`. How can `display` contain both the first and second number?

Comment: All your functions for the number keys do the same thing, except for the digit that they append. You should write a single function that takes the digit as a parameter, or get it from `this.id`, rather than writing 10 different functions.

Answer (score 2):

`calculate()` needs to parse the `display` field to get the two numbers and the operation. You can do this with a simple regular expression.

Also, you need to use `==` to compare strings, not `=`, which is for assigning.

There's no point in writing line like

```
firstNum + secondNum;
```

This calculates the sum but doesn't do anything with it. You only need the lines that assign the result of the calculation to the `display` value.

```js
function calculate() {
  var input = document.getElementById("display").value.match(/^(\d+)([+\-*\/])(\d+)$/);
  if (!input) {
    alert("Nothing to calculate");
    return;
  }
  var firstNum = parseInt(input[1]);
  var operation = input[2];
  var secondNum = parseInt(input[3]);
  if (operation == "+") {
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum + secondNum;
  } else if (operation == "-") {
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum - secondNum;
  } else if (operation == "/") {
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum / secondNum;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("display").value = firstNum * secondNum;
  }
}
```

Comment: Barmar one more question can u explain the code .match(/^(\d+)([+\-*\/])(\d+)$/); for me and if we have anything to replace that code because i have not learnt that.Tks man

Comment: Go to www.regular-expression.com to learn about regular expressions.